# ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Call to a member function

Tags: ооп, php, kohana

Здраствуйте.
Есть

```
$news=Model::factory('News')->get_news(3)->get_comms();
```

Суть: чтобы в массив с новостями, к каждой новости вывести комментарии.

Сделал передачу через this, но пишет

> ErrorException [ Fatal Error ]: Call to a member function get_comms() on a non-object

**Обновление**

- `get_news()` ищет записи в базе и выводит return `$this->news;`
- `get_comms()` с `$this->news` добавляет к каждой новости массив с комметариями и выводит.

Мне нужно чтобы к новостям выводились комментарии, но вот не знаю как сделать.

Comment: Что вам не понятно из этой надписи? "Call to a member function get_comms() on a non-object"

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Comment: get_news() должна возвращать объект класса News. Тогда такая цепочка сработает

Comment: mountpoint, 
всмысле в get_news() в начале вставить $n=Model::factory('News'); ?
Можно пример плиз